# Why my delpoy stage was not recognizedin gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: git, gitlab

Pipeline passed OK.
The first two are Ruby jobs,the last the Python but should cause any issues.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: ruby:2.6

variables:
  JEKYLL_ENV: production
  LC_ALL: C.UTF-8

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

stages:
- test
- build
- deploy


qa_test:
....
qa_build:
....
qa_deploy:
  image : python-latest
  tags:
  - docker
  stage: deploy
  environment:
   name : qa
  before_script:
   - pip install awscli
  script:
    - aws s3 cp ./qa s3://gitlab-jekyll-mycontainer/ --recursive
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - aq
  only:
    - except
```

First two stages passed,but it didn't try to run the deploy stage.
[image]
Why?

Comment: What is the `only: -except` in the deploy stage? Did you miss writing something there?

Comment: I will remove it,I followed the online tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
only: 
  - except
```

means the job will only run if you have a branch named `except`.

Create this branch or remove the `only` keyword to enable the job to run for all branches.